# Cannot declare a string

Tags: java, string

why is this actually happening? like on following screenshot :

[image]

Method is about to just return similiar phone numbers, the full code is :

```
 private String makeQueryForAllEqualNumbers (String number){
    String num1 = "0", num2 = "0";
    String res;
    if (number.startsWith("+") && number.length() == 12){    // +7965
        num1 = "" + (Integer.parseInt("" + number.charAt(1)) + 1) + number.substring(2); //8965
        num2 = "+" + number.substring(2); //+965
    }
    if (number.charAt(0) >= '0' && number.charAt(0) <=9 && number.length() == 11) {  //means 8965
        num1 = "+" + (Integer.parseInt("" + number.charAt(0)) - 1) + number.substring(1); //+7965
        num2 = "+" + number.substring(1);
    }
    else return number;
    res = number + "' OR ADDRESS = '" + num1 + "' OR ADDRESS = '" + num2;
    return res;
```

Comment: I'd set the breakpoint AFTER the variables have been assigned.

Comment: sry, but I will not search your screenshot for "what is actually happening"

Comment: It looks like the second `if` should be an `else if`.. not much information to go on other than that

Comment: sorry, what is happening?

Comment: What's wrong according to you?

Comment: I'm new to java, and although its seems explainable why uninitialized String variable is not displayed in debugger, method never returns String named res.

Comment: @TomMoto Given your actual code, the only way to return "res" is having the second if condition to be true. Is it the case?

Comment: you're `returning control then initializing` the `res` variable. and  if `both condition false` then `else return number will always executed`.

Comment: but the thing @user3145373 ツ told about using if else instead of  if  worked clearly

Comment: Still - why does string variable never appear in debuger after declaring till it's initialized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you will give only simple `else` then if above `both condition` will not satisfy then it will always `return control` so it's below line ll never executed.

so this line will not executed :

```
res = number + "' OR ADDRESS = '" + num1 + "' OR ADDRESS = '" + num2;
```

one way is to put `return` statement in `if` condition not in `else`.

Comment: @TomMoto : Hmm.. Keep Smiling. :)